# Word.Application ComObject errors in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, comobject, powershell-3.0

I'm unable to get a Word 2010 (14.0.x) document to [SaveAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRary/microsoft.office.interop.word.documentclass.saveas%28v=office.11%29) or [Close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRary/microsoft.office.interop.word.documentclass.close%28v=office.11%29) using Powershell. From all the tuts online it seems like it should be working with 2.0, but I don't have that anymore.

Simple case:

```
$Path = "C:\MyDoc.docx"
$Word = New-Object -comobject Word.Application
$Word.Visible = $True #Do this to close it out without task manager
$Doc = $Word.Documents.Open($Path)
$Doc.SaveAs($Path)
$Doc.Close()
```

At this point everything works up until the saving and closing:

```
Argument: '1' should be a System.Management.Automation.PSReference. Use [ref].
At line:5 char:1
+ $Doc.SaveAs($Path)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NonRefArgumentToRefParameterMsg

Argument types do not match
At line:6 char:1
+ $Doc.Close()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument types do not match
```

It seems like any methods that Get-Member shows as having arguments fail. For instance, calling a simple $Doc.Save() works fine, it seems. Looking at the MSDN info on those methods it looks like it takes things like the [SaveChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336792) method, but that's honestly beyond my skills at this point.

I've tried passing $Null or $True or $False in hopes of getting lucky, but it just keeps balking at me.

All I've been able to find is that it is apparently [linked to PS 3.0 Beta](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/thread/52d447fa-6c45-429e-a216-bf9a9e690670/) (seems to work fine in 2.0 for people) and a comment [Ed Wilson hasn't gotten back to](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/06/14/use-powershell-to-add-autocorrect-entries-to-word.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was also struggling al lot with this error, but got finally around it by calling the "Value" property of the PSReference (I got my Information here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psreference(v=vs.85).aspx )

this finally resulted in the codeLines:

```
$filename = [ref]"C:\Temp\pv_report.docx"    
[ref]$option = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat] -as [type]
$document.SaveAs(([ref]$filename).Value, ([ref]$option::wdFormatDocumentDefault).Value)
$document.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `[ref]` when you call `SaveAs`.  This worked for me:

```
$Path = "C:\MyDoc.docx"
$NewPath = "C:\MyDocRenamed.docx"
$Word = New-Object -comobject Word.Application
$Word.Visible = $True #Do this to close it out without task manager
$Doc = $Word.Documents.Open($Path)
$Doc.SaveAs([ref] $NewPath)
$Doc.Close()
```

Comment: No dice, still getting the 'Argument types do not match' error. I tried messing with [ref] prior, but to no avail. I'm not entirely sure WHAT is supposed to be referenced. Perhaps it's more than just PS version? I'm using Windows 7 64-bit, Powershell 3 beta and Office 14.0.6123.5001 64-bit, if that helps.

Comment: I was having the same issue and this solution worked for me.  Windows 7 64-bit, Powershell 2.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc626294(v=office.12).aspx#VSTO3PowerTools_OfficeInteropAPIExtensions

> **Office Interop API Extensions**
>
> The Office Interop API Extensions tool uses new features found in
>   Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 and Microsoft Visual C# 3.0 to wrap the
>   Office object model and provide a more productive environment for the
>   C# developer. Specifically, it employs extension methods, object
>   initializers, and nullable types to create a simplified,
>   strongly-typed, and, in some cases, Microsoft Visual Basic–like API.
>   It is not a complete managed API for Office, but is designed to
>   augment the raw object model in useful ways.
>
> The Office object model was originally targeted at dynamic languages
>   such as Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) and Visual
>   Basic. As such, it makes extensive use of some of their capabilities,
>   such as late-binding and optional parameters. Being an early-bound and
>   strongly-typed language, C# can be awkward, tedious, and error prone
>   when used in this context. The Office Interop API Extensions, with its
>   simplified and strongly-typed API, enables C# developers to be as
>   productive in this context as Visual Basic developers.

I know PowerShell 3.0 is based off of CLR4, but this assembly should still load ok. It removes the need for all of the [ref] parameters. Since a lot of this API is based on extension methods (something that doesn't exist in powershell) you'll have to pass the `$word` or `$doc` instance as the first parameter for a lot of the methods.

Comment: Tried downloading [VSTO_PTExtLibs.exe from the website](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7805) as specified in that doc to get the Interop Tools, but when I tried installing it the installer failed out due to me not having Visual Studio 2008 installed. I have VS 2010 already, so I don't think I'll be installing 2008 just to try this out. Besides, I was hoping to get something that would work on any PC that has Office installed, this would add another component required. I shall keep looking in the meantime, though, thanks!